# <hr> tag shows a tiny little edge

Tags: image

I used an [hr] tag but instead of just a single line it shows what seems to be the border of something. It has a teeny tiny little edge just on the left of it. The following link should explain what I mean.

[Image is here](http://postimg.org/image/lgm9vfa1b/7d4527d6/)

My code is as follows:

```
<hr align="center">
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate to "How to style the '<hr>' tag/element?" and/or "How to add borders to a div?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the default browser style. If you don't use any CSS that's what appears as the horizontal rule (`<hr />`) tag. For example this can be your markup:

```
<hr class="footer-hr" />
```

To style it you can use the following CSS code:

```
 .footer-hr {
 /* These are browser hacks so the horizontal line looks the same in all browsers
 (cross-browser) */
 border-color: #000000;
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #000000;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 /* So keep them as they are - you can change the values of course */
 }
```

Also why would you align it to the center, the browser does it by default as I know. Also if you add something like `margin: 0px;` in CSS you can have the `<hr />` wrap the whole line of the page, from the farest left to the farest right corner.

EDIT:
To make the line not to look fat you could use this:

Add to the above CSS code the following rule:

```
height: 1px; /* Or change the value to whatever other number */
```

EDIT 2:
As you asked for a bordered div, I don't know what did you want a top-border or a bottom-border or both? Anyway here's the code you need:

***MARKUP:***

```
<div class="bordered-div"><!-- Some content here --></div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.bordered-div {
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but now it's too fat, even when on 1px. Do you know how to make it even smaller?

PS. I'm not very experienced with HTML nor CSS so I guess that's why I did it.

Comment: Hmmm... Did you try replacing the    solid

Comment: I accidentally edited your comment, sorry for that. My question is "with what should I replace it?"

Comment: Well you could try this: `border: 0px none #000000;`

Comment: The line on this page right above the black "Answer your question" button would be perfect. I already checked the source code but that didn't bear any fruits.

Comment: Edited the answer to match what you want. Experiment. Also that is a div's border, not a `<hr>`. If that is what you wanted, then mark this as answer to help other users that have the same question.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the line above "Answer your question" is a div border? How do I make one like those?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I have been looking for! Thank you **so** much!